# Where are gedit's preferences?

Tags: configuration, gedit

This is incredibly weird. I don't see "preferences" in any of my gedit menus. I'm running Version 3.8.3. All I want to do is show line numbers, but I can't do that without preferences.

Where the heck are they hiding?

note: I did remove `indicator-appmenus` because I dislike having the menus detached from the window.

2015 Update: somehow this is being flagged as a dupe of [Enable line numbers in gedit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/364117/enable-line-numbers-in-gedit) which is a little confusing. The solution is the same but the questions are different.

Comment: Does your gEdit have a gear icon in the main window toolbar area?

Comment: @dobey no, it doesn't.

Comment: Eeesh. @vasa1 It does. Editing my Q

Comment: iwould ck here as the issue was no preference menu option http://askubuntu.com/questions/364117/enable-line-numbers-in-gedit/364763#364763

Comment: @doug running `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings overrides '@a{sv} {"Gtk/ShellShowsAppMenu": <int32 0>}'` as described there doesn't do anything for me.

Comment: What did work was explicitly setting line numbers w/ ` gsettings set org.gnome.gedit.preferences.editor display-line-numbers true `

Comment: @user5950  I accepted an answer to this two years ago.  I am not even running the same version of gedit anymore.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I'm not sure how to get `preferences` back in your menus, but you can use [`gsettings`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/gsettings.1.html) to display line numbers. Enter this command into the terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.gedit.preferences.editor display-line-numbers true
```

In case you need to change other settings for `gedit`, you can use this command to find quite a few that are available: (thanks to [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/219054/198090) answer)

```
gsettings list-recursively | grep -i gedit
```

Comment: cannot believe why gedit became so hard to use these days....

Comment: +1 because this answer is valid for Gedit in GNOME 3.12 and probably for newer releases also. Gedit in newer releases doesn't seem to have the preferences dialog [as described here](https://blogs.gnome.org/nacho/2014/01/15/gedit-has-a-new-face/).

Answer (score 52):

if you are using GNOME 3, you can access the preferences via the top menu.

you should have "activities" on the top left corner of your screen. on the right side of activities, you will have gedit. click on it, and you should see the preferences.

Comment: I do see preferences, but clicking it doesn't bring up anything.

Comment: @Power-Inside if you've got a top menu but the "preferences" menu item isn't doing anything, you probably want to start a new question.

Comment: ew! yet another reason for me not to return to gnome. why move *preferences* to a mac style location?? absurd

Comment: It helps me. Thank you! I found a lot of tips for accessing through "edit" menu, however I couldn't find on my Ubuntu GNOME 16.04. I couldn't imagine that it moved onto a global menu.

Comment: launching it with sudo the preferences are in the standard three-bar, and not the top bar,  and preferences are locked (gedit 3.30 under Arch)

Comment: @user1708042 You can have `sudo -H gedit` inherit user preferences though: https://askubuntu.com/questions/270006/why-should-users-never-use-normal-sudo-to-start-graphical-applications/1047413#1047413

Comment: "top menu" is the bit on the gnome desktop top bar that says "Text Editor" or "gedit" wnen gedit is focussed

Comment: I don't get this mad dash by designers to remove the menu. *Leave the menu alone. Its useful*

Answer (score 20):

To get the preferences entry back to the edit menu perform the following command in a terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings overrides '@a{sv} {"Gtk/ShellShowsAppMenu": <int32 0>}'
```

The problem results from Gnome3 putting the preferences menu entry to the top menu.

Comment: Thank you, this was the only solution that worked for me (using CentOS but solution is the same). Can't believe this is hidden by default!!

Answer (score 16):

Just type <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, then again <kbd>E</kbd> when you are in gedit. A new window called "gedit Preferences" should appear.

[image: gedit preferences]

Comment: No dice, I'm afraid.

Comment: @Amanda I am using gedit 3.8.3 in Ubuntu 13.10 and this is how I open preferences in gedit. I made you also a picture to prove you.

Comment: I believe you, but my edit menu ends at "Insert Date and Time"

Comment: @Amanda You can also use `gsettings` to change `gedit`'s settings.

Comment: This works for me: `gsettings set org.gnome.gedit.preferences.editor display-line-numbers true`

Comment: Boom. @OSE ... you should make that an answer.

Comment: @Amanda + it can be that gedit has different outfit in menu, whether you use Gnome, or Unity or simply xfce4 (to save memory).

Comment: The best excellent solution without the command line!!

Comment: I don't understand this solution at all. For me pressing <Alt>+`e` then `e` while `gedit` is active just put an `e` into the edit window.

Answer (score 4):

Faced similar problem...got the preference option in the activities bar in the left hand corner..I am using gedit v3.22.1

[gedit preference setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGslG.png)

[image]

Comment: That option wasn't available for me, just current document, _New Window_, _New Document_ and _Remove from Favorites_.

Answer (score 3):

You may need to use tweak tool to turn off temporarily some of the common extensions normal people now use to make gnome 3 usable on a desktop.  For me, I had to turn off the taskbar and applications menu extensions.  Then one can use the method described by Buğra Koç above.

This means the easy switching on and off of line numbers and word wrap in gedit is gone.

If you don't need text highlighting Leafpad is a good replacement for gedit.  It looks like the old gedit:

```
sudo apt-get install leafpad
```

Comment: Even when I turn off all extensions, I don't see the Preferences options in either the top menu or the hamburger menu. The only way which works for me is to just show the app menus, see https://askubuntu.com/a/671398/19011

Answer (score 3):

In my desktop, I found it here:
[image]

Comment: That is the best answer for me! No need to use cli or disable ui extensions.
Just right-click gedit icon in panel - and you got it!
You just saved my day, thanks a lot!

Comment: That option wasn't available for me, just current document, _New Window_, _New Document_ and _Remove from Favorites_.

Comment: The question is asking how to get to Preferences when it doesn't show in any menus like this!

Answer (score 1):

You can access the preference settings of any app by installing [dconf-editor](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/dconf):

Debian derivatives:

```
sudo apt install dconf-editor
```

Redhat derivatives:

```
sudo yum install dconf-editor # for Fedora replace yum with dnf
```

Then open dconf-editor

```
dconf-editor &>/dev/null &
```

Click the search icon and type `gedit` or follow this path:        `org/gnome/gedit/preference/editor/display-line-number`

Turn off the default value and make the custom value `true`

Answer (score 0):

The preferences are under edit at the bottom of the list.
[image]

Try to get the menu-bar back, or if that fails remove it entirely and install a fresh new instance of gedit, mine is 3.10.4, so yours is a bit old!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but I just ran into the same problem. In the end, I figured out that it was because I was still logged in as the superuser. Once I logged out of the terminal and reopened the terminal, everything went back to normal.

Just thought I'd throw that out there in case anyone else hits the same problem.

If you're seeing a # instead of a $ at your command line, this is likely why you can't see your defaults.

Comment: Although this is true, it doesn't explain how to access preferences when using `gedit` with super user `sudo` powers.

Answer (score 0):

Some preferences, such as *display line numbers* can be activated from the options in the gedit bottom bar(right side).