# How to search for specific lines in Linux?

Tags: command-line, search

I recently received an error telling me that there was a problem on line 52. I am trying to learn what the best method is for finding lines instead of actually counting them.

In Windows, I often used [Notepad++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B) which displayed the lines directly to the left, so users could easily scroll to the specific line they were looking for -- However I do not see this option in Linux.

Maybe a certain application is needed?

---

**UPDATE:** I currently can not open software-store and the only text editor I have is the default `nano` and `gedit`. So please restrict your answers to solutions that don't involve me installing software.

**NOTE: ** I am not looking to find a 'String' of some sort. I am looking to quickly find the line NUMBER that the string appears on.

Comment: @EliahKagan This is the same as the answer that dlundy1 gave when he answered his own question. Read my comment  again, especially the part about the arrow in the screenshot, and then read dlundy1's answer. My comment was intended to be an improvement on dlundy1's answer to his own question as he described it in the question's title.

Comment: @EliahKagan The title of the question is *How to Search for Specific LINES in Linux?*. In the question dlundy1 also writes *So please restrict your answers to solutions that don't involve me installing software.* Gedit is installed by default in Ubuntu, so I am showing dlundy1 how to show line numbers in Gedit.

Comment: @karel But [that answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/375050) is still a workaround for a problem that doesn't apply here. The OP there knew that to show left-side line numbers one uses the Preferences dialog, and the problem was how to access that in the presence of a bug that made the menu item difficult to access. This question is very different--an answer showing how to access it in the normal way (click Edit, click Preferences, check "Display line numbers" in the View tab) would apply here. *Closing this as a duplicate of that would only deceive people into thinking that bug still applies.*

Comment: Which `gedit` version you are using?

Comment: voted to re-open. Although the problem is with sources.list , and although the problem is a dup, the question is how to find a line in a text file. IMO the answer is with sed, although grep, awk, perl (to name a few) can do this as can head and tail

Comment: Oddly enough, I was the only person to include a GUI option in my answer. While I myself am a console junkie, in the context of this question (namely, his reference to Notepad++) I believe he was looking for a GUI option, not that sed/grep/awk/perl/etc couldn't do it as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're looking for a GUI approach, you can display line numbers in the default text editor, gedit. To do this, go to Edit -> Preferences and tick the box that says "Display line numbers."

You can also jump to a specific line number by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>.

Comment: Thank You! this partially worked. (ctrl + i)

However I do not see Edit button in gedit

Comment: Well, to be honest that was kind of a guess. I run GNOME Shell in the menu is in a different place. Let me boot up a VM.

Comment: In the default desktop environment, Unity, hover over the very top of the screen where it says "Text Editor" and you get your menu bar. It is, indeed Edit->Preferences. In my desktop environment of choice, GNOME Shell, you have to click up top on the activities bar where it says "Gedit" and then go to Preferences.

Answer (score 8):

Let's create a test file;

```
$ seq 100 >file
```

Now, let's display line 52:

```
$ sed -n 52p file
52
```

Or:

```
$ awk 'NR==52' file
52
```

Or, if you have the file open in `vim`, you can type `52G` to jump to line 52.

#### Using nano

Suppose that your file is called `file.txt`.  To edit the file in `nano` with line, column, and character count displayed, run

```
nano -c file.txt
```

This is what nano looks like with the cursor on line 7 of a 21-line file:
[image]

Comment: I  don't understand your answer, John. Also because I am unfamiliar with the syntax I have no base of interpreting your scenario into my specific situation. Could you provide a more literal example.  also, I am unable to download vim

Comment: @dlundy1 What is the name of your file?  Suppose it was called `file.c`.  In that case, at the command line, run the command `sed -n 52p file.c` and you will see line 52 displayed. (The `sed` command is standard with Linux: no install needed.)

Comment: @dlundy1 I see that you use `nano`.  I have also added a `nano` solution for display line numbers.

Answer (score 5):

You can display the file with `less`. Use `less -N` to display line numbers, type "`52`" to `less` to get to line 52. See `man less`.

Or, you could open the file with the `vim` editor (type `vim thefile`), then typing "`:52`" will get you to line 52.  See `man vim`

Comment: I am unfamiliar with this command, so if you could use it within context that would be great.

Also I don't have vim and cannot open software-store until I fix an error related to this post.

Comment: @dlundy1 if you don't have `vim`, you still have `vi`, which while more basic, still supports navigating to line numbers.

Answer (score 5):

In `vi` or `vim`

`:set nu` turns on line numbers

`:set nonu` turns off line numbers

`52gg` goes to line 52

`52G` also goes to line 52

Comment: `vi` and `vim` can also be told to show line numbers and to position the cursor at the beginning of a specific line, at the time they are launched: `vi '+set nu' +52` (If you like, please feel free to add this information to your answer.)

Answer (score 1):

Hey everyone I think many of us completely over-thought this.
As I continued reading through your comments and Answers, I realized
that the basic text editor tells you what line and Column you are on if you look at the bottom of the window. :/

I feel silly lol

Comment: Well, could you please find one of the interesting or most practical answers listed here and accept one ? At least for the sake of protocol , you know

Answer (score 0):

A good tool for the job is `grep`. With `grep -i -n 'string'` you can search for a particular string and find out what line it is on.

Suppose java compiler reports me an error that in line `System.out.println("Hello World")` I have no semicolon or something like that.

What I could do is to `cat helloworld.java | grep -i -n 'hello world'`

And this would return  me `7:       System.out.println("Hello World!")` , where 7: is the line number with colon as separator.

Alternatively, you can start nano with cursor on a particular line and column like so `nano +7,0 helloworld.java` (and by the way this is one of the first options in the `man nano`)

Comment: I didn't downvote it but OP wants to display a line whose number is known already, I think you missunderstood the question

Comment: OP said in the post " I am looking to quickly find the line NUMBER that the string appears on " which is what I addressed.

Comment: You are right, sorry, in fact it's badly explained and I would have been fooled as well. But actually if you read at the start of the post: "I recently received an error telling me that there was a problem on LINE 52, I am trying to learn what the best method is for finding lines instead of actually counting them." and what comes after it's clear that he rather wants a way to display line N

Comment: I left the comment because I saw the non explained downvote, so I tought it would have clarified to you why it was downvoted

Comment: Thank you, kos, I do appreciate when users point out areas where I can improve.