# Gedit showing preferences option in edit menu only when I open gedit using sudo gedit

Tags: 15.10, gedit

Gedit preferences option is not displayed when I open a text file by double-clicking. However, when I open gedit by using `sudo gedit` command from terminal, preferences option will be displayed. But, the changes made in that preferences will not be seen in the gedit opened by double-clicking the file.

I know that we can change different preferences from terminal, but I need that preferences option itself to be displayed.

I am using Ubuntu 15.10 and I have installed gnome UI (gdm). I have also changed file permissions to check if it was permission problem.

How can I make that preferences option appear in gedit even when I open it by double-clicking text file ?

Edit:

*This question is not duplicate of  [Where are gedit's preferences?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/375049/where-are-gedits-preferences). This is a different situation here. I was getting that option when opened using `sudo gedit` but not when opened by double-clicking. Also, I needed the method to make preferences option appear, for which I couldn't find question anywhere and I want to know why `sudo gedit` works for me.*

Edit 2:

I would also like to know why running `sudo gedit` displays preferences option while double-clicking file doesn't.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where are gedit's preferences?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/375049/where-are-gedits-preferences)

Comment: I deleted my answer since I found a duplicate, this answer worked for me: http://askubuntu.com/a/671398/380067

Comment: @kos Check my edit. I asked the method to enable it, which is not asked anywhere in askubuntu.

Comment: "How can I make that preferences option appear in gedit even when I open it by double-clicking text file ?": the answer is in the [linked question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/375049/where-are-gedits-preferences), and specifically in [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/671398/380067).

Comment: @kos Yes. I saw it. But that was not the perfect answer for that question. The questioner mainly wanted to enable the line number. _He didn't ask how to enable the option_. So, my question is not a duplicate.

Comment: Please post output of `stat -c  "%A %u %n" $HOME/.config/gedit/* `

Comment: @Serg Note that the output of that command is likely irrelevant in this case, because before voting to close I tried to run `sudo gedit` and couldn't find any file owned by root in my home directory afterwards.

Comment: Varun Sharma, do you actually want to know why running `sudo gedit` displays the context menu entry and why opening gedit by double-clicking on a text file doesn't? If so please rephrase your question like so and I'll remove my close vote, but if just want to know just how to enable the context menu entry when opening gedit by double-clicking on a text file there's really no reason to leave this question open.

Comment: @Serg varun@ubuntu:~$ stat -c "%A %u %n" $HOME/.config/gedit/*
-rw-r--r-- 0 /home/varun/.config/gedit/accels

Comment: @kos I would like to know why sudo gedit works and I have modified question.

Comment: You have a root owned file `/home/varun/.config/gedit/accels` . Try deleting or moving that file out of the `.config/gedit` directory, see if that helps