# Gedit preference only available to superuser

Tags: gedit, preferences

I have an annoying issue with gedit on Ubuntu 18.04. Only under `sudo gedit` when I can see/change preferences. Appreciate any experience to a solution.
Tried all the [methods](https://askubuntu.com/questions/720171/gedit-showing-preferences-option-in-edit-menu-only-when-i-open-gedit-using-sudo) I can [find](https://askubuntu.com/questions/728863/cant-change-gedit-preferences-and-terminal-preferences-dont-save) such as [removing the accels file](http:///home/varun/.config/gedit/accels) including re-install gedit, none resolved the problem.
This [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92655/how-can-i-sync-my-root-gedit-with-my-user-gedits-preferences?noredirect=1&lq=1) is the closest to the problem, but I still do not know how to retain the settings for regular user. Appreciate any insight.

Comment: What's the ownership/permission situation? `sudo find $HOME \! -user $USER -ls`, and `find $HOME \! -readable` will point out problems.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on ownership/permission situation? You command lines gave a too long list to be posted here.

Comment: This is a main reason why running GUI programs as `root` is a Bad Idea. They update files in your `$HOME/...` as `root`. Later, as `$USER`, troubling

Comment: Thanks! Your comment emphasizes using gedit (or any other GUI apps!) under root is bad.  Actually I did not use gedit as root, and I do not want to. I wish you could suggest a solution, if possible.

Comment: @Yifangt Let me know if this potential duplicate solves your problem: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1045114/gedit-manage-external-tools-menu-option-doesnt-appear

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix --I should have read the  post https://askubuntu.com/questions/1045114/gedit-manage-external-tools-menu-option-doesnt-appear first. But, unfortunately, it did not work! Also I check the ownership/permission, for those under my home/ all have the right ownership.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the files and directories under `$HOME` that don't belong to you (to your `$USER`) with (note `sudo` - this needs to run as `root`):

```
sudo find $HOME \! -user $USER -print
```

If you want to change the owner back to you, you can (this will handle funny filenames, too):

```
sudo find $HOME \! -user $USER -print0 | xargs -0 sudo chown --verbose $(id -u):$(id -g)
```

Comment: Thanks! I checked the permission of the folder/files in my home directory, all are correct. especially gedit and related are under my ownership.