# How can I force gedit 44.2 to open file in the UTF-8 encoding?

Tags: gedit, encoding, utf-8

I'm on Ubuntu 23.10 using gedit 44.2. I opened a file named `METADATA`, and it displayed like this:

[image: Screenshot of mojibake]

However, if I open it with another file editor, I see these contents:

```
Metadata-Version: 2.1
Name: pyright
Version: 1.1.337
Summary: Command line wrapper for pyright
...
```

It seems that gedit did not correctly recognise the file encoding to be UTF-8, and opened it using another encoding. How can I ask gedit to open the file using UTF-8?

Comment: Maybe try some of these changes the gedit preferences https://askubuntu.com/questions/375049/where-are-gedits-preferences than?

Comment: @darth_epoxy There isn't a preference to do with encoding, as far as I can see. That question is 10 years old, by the way, and gedit has changed a lot since then.

Comment: Have you been able to confirm what the encoding actually is (e.g. using the `file` command)?

Comment: Sorry for the old link @Flimm but that's how long ago anyone used gedit :) Have you tried using nano for file editing?

Comment: `gedit --encoding=UTF-8 '/a/file' `

Comment: @steeldriver Yes, I have.

Comment: @cmak.fr Thank you! I would accept that as an answer.