# How to re-enable wordwrap in gedit?

Tags: 13.10, gedit

In previous versions of Ubuntu, gedit had a wordwrap option available in the menu option Edit -> Preferences -> View -> Enable text wrapping.

[image: screenshot of gedit preferences in Ubuntu 13.04]

But in Ubuntu 13.10, I don't see a Preferences menu anymore.  How do I toggle word wrapping?

[image: screenshot of gedit in Ubuntu 13.10]

Comment: Are http://askubuntu.com/questions/375049/where-are-gedits-preferences or http://askubuntu.com/a/364140/25656 related?

Comment: Might be related.  Like that person, my "edit" menu ends at "Insert Date and Time" as I posted in the screenshot.  Where did the Preferences menu item go?

Comment: Did you remove `indicator-appmenus`? If you did then see if http://askubuntu.com/a/364763/25656 helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, that ever-annoying app-menu!  Thanks, @vasa1, that seems to have done the trick.  If anyone else runs into this, the solution is to paste this in a terminal window:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings overrides '@a{sv} {"Gtk/ShellShowsAppMenu": <int32 0>}'
```

I didn't have to reboot or logout.  As soon as I restarted gedit, the Preferences menu item was available.

(Bonus points to anyone who know what that arcane @a{sv...} text means!?)